# Complex analysis, integrating along a line segment

Tags: complex-analysis

Sorry for not being able to use proper symbols for what's coming, I've been stuck with this issue for about 2 hours, gonna try to my luck here.

It's the integral of $1/(1+z^2)$ along the line segment from $z =1$ to $z=1+i$.

My answer is $$(-\pi/4) - 1/2(\arctan(2)) + (i/4)\log(5),$$ but it's supposed to be $$(+\pi/4) - 1/2(\arctan(2)) + (i/4)\log(5).$$

Hopefully someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: it is easier to see what's happening with $2i\frac{1}{1+z^2} = \frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z+i}$ so that (where everything is analytic) $\int \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz = \frac{1}{2i} ( \log(z-i)-\log(z+i) )$. Now there is an analytic branch of $\log(z-i)$ and $\log(z+i)$ on $z \in [1,1+i]$,  find it and you'll get the correct result

Comment: I have a hard time understanding branch cuts at all, but isnt (-pi/2,3pi/2) good enough?

Comment: do you know a branch of $\log$ that is analytic on the segment $[1-i,1+2i]$ ? yes : the usual (principal branch) complex logarithm. Hence, you can use it as an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{z-i}$ and $\frac{1}{z+i}$ on $[1,1+i]$